# Random URL's in Apache access.log

Tags: apache2, proxy

My server recently started getting a massive increase in the number of random URL requests.

- `124.173.67.77 - - [23/Jul/2016:21:21:04 -0400] "GET http://www.059boss.com/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 12040 "http://www.059boss.com/index.php" "http://www.059boss.com/index.php"`
- `195.182.131.107 - - [23/Jul/2016:21:21:04 -0400] "GET http://ascon-profi.ru/common/proxy.php HTTP/1.1" 404 474 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208"`
- `155.94.224.168 - - [23/Jul/2016:21:21:04 -0400] "GET http://www.daqimeng.com/user/login HTTP/1.1" 404 470 "http://www.baidu.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`
- `119.29.32.85 - - [23/Jul/2016:21:21:04 -0400] "GET http://www.tianx.top/ HTTP/1.0" 200 11992 "http://www.so.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.8.0.11) Gecko/20070312 Firefox/1.5.0.11; 360Spider"`

These all look like proxy requests, but some are (some of them) returning 200 responses, which is definitely NOT a good thing.  I'm reasonably sure that mod_proxy isn't enabled anywhere, but it's possible it is.  How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the 404 responses are when the GET URL includes a sub-directory and that the 200 responses are when the GET URL does not include a sub-directory. For the 200 responses, the web page that is delivered is actually the document root web page from your site and not the GET URL.

Answer (score 2):

Those have nothing to do with proxies. The web browsers that submitted those `GET` requests think that your server's IP address is just fine for the domain they're trying to reach. This could be for any number of reasons. Perhaps their DNS server is broken.

### How to handle domain names that don't belong to your server

According to [the Apache web server documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html), the first `VirtualHost` entry will be used to handle random hosts that you don't define in another `VirtualHost` entry:

> Due to the fact that the virtual host with `ServerName www.example.com` is first in the configuration file, it has the highest priority and can be seen as the *default* or *primary* server.

So, add a new `VirtualHost` entry before all others like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bad-domain
  ServerAlias *
  Redirect 404 /
  ErrorDocument 404 "Page Not Found"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That is the reason why the default VH configuration file is named `000-default.conf` it should be included first in `apache2.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually they can have something to do with a proxy... If you have set up Apache as a proxy (using **ProxyRequests On** in your config file) and you see those URLs with a 200 message, that means Apache happily downloaded the data from the distant server and sent it back to the client connected to your computer.

Source: spotted this on a customer's misconfigured Apache server.